# Lightweight, multi-platform, remote desktop program running directly

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, remote-desktop, intranet

I have at work, a very specific network environment for testing satellite connection, which we have a computer that is connected to the satellite environment. Over this network we then connected to the computer using Microsoft Remote Desktop, and TeamViewer when a non Windows PC was connecting.

We have now changed the setup because the computer ran on a Windows Server 2012 R2 trial license, and is now running Cub Linux, which then killed the MS RD usage and we decided to run a separate network to it for not taking too much bandwidth from using RD, monitoring software etc. over the satellite

The problem is now that we want to only run internal traffic through that new network which eliminate TeamViewer, because of, that connection will not run directly from point A to point B and instead runs to the TeamViewer servers before connecting to the intended targeted device.

What we are looking for is a remote desktop program that is:

- Multi-platform that runs on both Windows PC and Linux (Debian-/Ubuntu-based).
- Lightweight. We had performance problems with Ubuntu being too heavy, so it has to be as lightweight as possible.
- FREE! We currently have the problem of overspending, which is the reason for using Linux instead of buying Windows license for it.
- Point to Point connection or something which we can have a server internal in our network.
- While not a must-have requirement, we want it to be relative easy to set up and use.

We have tried Google Chrome Remote Desktop, but it didn't work on our machine (the button for enable remote connection was missing on the Linux machine), and we have ran out of TeamViewer users in our business license, and have only an older version (version 7) license with available users left which doesn't work with the rest of our equipment (running version 10), and we are now out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [**RealVNC**](https://www.realvnc.com/download/) for both internal LAN connections and external connections. It can work on both ways.

- Furthermore, it supports a variety of platforms. In short it supports both **Windows** and **Linux**.
- Plus, its lightweight.
- It uses the client-server communication model. Either platform (Windows or Linux) can be a server or run a client.

A [short guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-RealVNC) to get you started on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), a free implementation of the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). Works on Linux, macOS and Windows.